# Update action is not working when "if condition" is introduced in active form YII2

Tags: php, if-statement, yii2

Below is the _form.php (only if condition)

```
 <?php if($model->certified =='n') :  ?>

        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q1')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q2')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q3')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q4')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q5')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q6')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q7')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q8')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q9')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q10')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q11')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q12')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q13')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q14')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q15')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

 <?php else: ?> 

        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q16')->textInput() ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelcertificate, 'description')->dropDownList(
                                             ArrayHelper::map(CertificateDescription::find()->all(),'description','description'),
                                            [   'prompt'=>'select desc', 

                                            ]); ?>  

        <?= $form->field($modelcertificate, 'types')->dropDownList(
                                             ArrayHelper::map(CertificateType::find()->all(),'type','type'),
                                            [   'prompt'=>'select type', 

                                            ]); ?>    


        <?= $form->field($modelcertificate, 'file')->fileInput() ?>
        <?= $form->field($modelcertificate, 'validity')->textInput() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The above code works fine(once tables are updated, navigates to view).  But when I change the position of the **else** statement, that is placing else after *** field($modelqm, 'q16')->textInput() ?>*** (after immediate next line) Update doesn't happen. it just reloads the update form(page) with new values entered but these values won't be saved into database tables.

**I have checked the div tag I don't have any unclosed tags. interchanged contents in if and else condition but it doesn't resolve the issue.

What could be the reason for this kind of behavior? Has anyone faced this kind of issue?? How do I solve this

update action:-

```
public function actionUpdate()
{

    $id = Yii::$app->user->getId();
    $command = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['id'])
        ->from('supplier')
        ->where(['user_id' => $id])
        ->createCommand();

// returns all rows of the query result
    $rows = $command->queryAll();

    $model = $this->findModel($rows);


    $id1 = $model->id;
    $command1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['id'])
        ->from('supplier_noqm')
        ->where(['supplier_id' => $id1])
        ->createCommand();

// returns all rows of the query result
    $rows1 = $command1->queryAll();


    $modelqm = $this->findModel1($rows1);

    $command2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['id'])
        ->from('supplier_certificate')
        ->where(['supplier_id' => $id1])
        ->createCommand();

// returns all rows of the query result
    $rows2 = $command2->queryAll();


    $modelcertificate = $this->findSupplierCertificateModel($rows2);
    $modelsSupManpower = $model->supManpowers;
    $modelsSupCompanyid = $model->supCompanies;
    $modelsSupOtherplace = $model->supOtherplaces;


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelqm->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelcertificate->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
var_dump($model->validate(), $model->errors);die;
        $user = $this->findUserModel($model->user_id);
        $user->pin = $model->pin;
        $user->country = $model->country;
        $user->state = $model->state;
        $user->city = $model->city;
        $user->save();


        $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsSupManpower, 'id', 'id');
        $modelsSupManpower = Model::createMultiple(SupManpower::classname(), $modelsSupManpower);
        Model::loadMultiple($modelsSupManpower, Yii::$app->request->post());
        $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsSupManpower, 'id', 'id')));

        $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsSupCompanyid, 'id', 'id');
        $modelsSupCompanyid = Model::createMultiple(SupCompanyid::classname(), $modelsSupCompanyid);
        Model::loadMultiple($modelsSupCompanyid, Yii::$app->request->post());
        $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsSupCompanyid, 'id', 'id')));

        $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsSupOtherplace, 'id', 'id');
        $modelsSupOtherplace = Model::createMultiple(SupOtherplace::classname(), $modelsSupOtherplace);
        Model::loadMultiple($modelsSupOtherplace, Yii::$app->request->post());
        $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsSupOtherplace, 'id', 'id')));


// ajax validation
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ArrayHelper::merge(
                ActiveForm::validateMultiple($modelsSupManpower),
                ActiveForm::validateMultiple($modelsSupOtherplace),
                ActiveForm::validate($model)
            );
        }

// validate all models
        $valid = $model->validate();
        $valid = $modelqm->validate() && $valid;
        $valid = $modelcertificate->validate() && $valid;
        $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsSupManpower) && $valid;
        $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsSupCompanyid) && $valid;
        $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsSupOtherplace) && $valid;


        if ($valid) {

            $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            try {
                if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                    $modelqm->supplier_id = $model->id;
                    $modelcertificate->supplier_id = $model->id;
                    $modelqm->save(false);
                    if ($modelcertificate->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($modelcertificate, 'file')) {
                        $name = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
                        $randnum = rand(pow(10, 5 - 1), pow(10, 5) - 1);
                        $imageName = $name . $randnum;

//$path = 'machinephotos/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->image->extension;
                        $modelcertificate->file->saveAs('certuploads/' . $imageName . '.' . $modelcertificate->file->extension);
                        $modelcertificate->filename = 'certuploads/' . $imageName . '.' . $modelcertificate->file->extension;
                        $modelcertificate->file = null;
                        $modelcertificate->save(false);

                    }
                    $model->file = null;
                    if (!($flag = $modelcertificate->save(false))) {

                        $transaction->rollBack();

                    }

                    if (!empty($deletedIDs)) {
                        SupManpower::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
                    }
                    foreach ($modelsSupManpower as $modelSupManpower) {
                        $modelSupManpower->supplier_id = $model->id;
                        if (!($flag = $modelSupManpower->save(false))) {
                            $transaction->rollBack();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!empty($deletedIDs)) {
                        SupCompanyid::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
                    }
                    foreach ($modelsSupCompanyid as $modelSupCompanyid) {
                        $modelSupCompanyid->supplier_id = $model->id;
                        if (!($flag = $modelSupCompanyid->save(false))) {
                            $transaction->rollBack();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!empty($deletedIDs)) {
                        SupOtherplace::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
                    }
                    foreach ($modelsSupOtherplace as $modelSupOtherplace) {
                        $modelSupOtherplace->supplier_id = $model->id;
                        if (!($flag = $modelSupOtherplace->save(false))) {
                            $transaction->rollBack();
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                }
                if ($flag) {
                    $transaction->commit();

                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                }
          } catch (Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollBack();
            }
        }
    }

    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->get());
    $model->production_scope = ArrayHelper::map($model->parts, 'part_name', 'part_name');
    $model->target_industry = ArrayHelper::map($model->industries, 'name', 'name');
    $model->material = ArrayHelper::map($model->materials, 'name', 'name');
    $model->inspection_specialities = ArrayHelper::map($model->inspections, 'name', 'name');

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelqm' => $modelqm,
        'modelcertificate' => $modelcertificate,
        'modelsSupManpower' => (empty($modelsSupManpower)) ? [new SupManpower] : $modelsSupManpower,
        'modelsSupCompanyid' => (empty($modelsSupCompanyid)) ? [new SupCompanyid] : $modelsSupCompanyid,
        'modelsSupOtherplace' => (empty($modelsSupOtherplace)) ? [new SupOtherplace] : $modelsSupOtherplace


    ]);

}
```

Comment: Are you tried to use brackets? if ( condition ) { #code  } else { #code }

Comment: @tigrasti He used better standard in views. @Rachna after `$model->load()` just try `var_dump($model->validate(), $model->errors);die;`

Comment: @Yupik, I have added but i don't see any changes

Comment: @Rachna did U tried sending form now?

Comment: @yupik Yes, I have added `var_dump($model->validate(), $model->errors);die;` after $model->load() in update controller action and then tried to update the form. but i see no changes.  Do you want me to  post code for Update action?

Comment: @Rachna If nothing happens - yes, we definitely need action code :)

Comment: @Yupik I have update the question with update action code.

Comment: Propably the problem is in `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelqm->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelcertificate->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {` line -> u have to check POST to see which doesnt exists in submitted data.